# Are AWS security groups enough to segment network and reduce PCI scope?

Tags: pci-dss, aws, pci-scope

I was reading this paper

https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/pci-dss-scoping-on-aws.pdf

It shows this image

[image]

Am I correct in saying that - as long as instances have proper security groups that restrict connectivity, it will remove them from PCI scope?

On an additional note - is it just me that finds it awfully difficult to get best practice for PCI within cloud environments - seems a bit all over the place.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use NACLs too, right?

Comment: @Ian of course!

Comment: More serious answer: I *assume* that the security group is configured to FW spec, then they will be appeased. http://info.securitymetrics.com/how-to-implement-and-maintain-pci-compliant-firewalls-wp?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=wp-how-to-implement-and-maintain-pci-firewalls couple this with the scoping suggestions, and you should be golden! https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Guidance-PCI-DSS-Scoping-and-Segmentation_v1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiop6WJ1aLjAhWDURUIHQyGAS4QFjABegQIEBAI&usg=AOvVaw0zWC3r-xXedNQ0jM6fpH4y

Comment: @Ian i am just going to quote that whitepaper in my discussions with them

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No
But it helps a lot.

In AWS VPC there are at least 3 (I prefer a 4th too but i'll leave it out of this answer, there may be more than 4 anyway) types of network segmentation:

1. VPC default settings segments itself from other VPCs in the same account and other accounts; i.e. it is non-transitive routing so consider you have VPC Peering in use; VPC A can speak to VPC B, B can speak to C, but A cannot speak to C through B. Essentially VPC inherently provides independent verifiable segmentation and you don't need to do anything unless you want to do further segmentation within the same VPC.
2. Transit Gateway fine-grained routing configurations which are onerous and non-default behaviour, and actually breaks (1) VPC non-transitive routing entirely so now you get no 'default segmentation' provided by AWS VPC inherently, you need to add that segmentation back in yourself AND then add any further segmentation rules required.
3. Overlay networks, such as those deployed with Kubernetes or Network devices like Palo Alto. These overlay networks are similar to a Transit Gateway and break the inherent segmentation guarantee, so you will again have to first bring your overlay network segmentation configuration back up to the same level you had by default in a VPC and then consider adding further segmentation afterwards if you require it.

You can also find some AWS boilerplate PCI DSS ready architectures [here](https://accelerate.amazonaws.com/portal/signin) (requires login)